# Error: No device found matching --device Pixel 3a when using avdmanager

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I am using android sdk tools avdmanager to create some emulators.

When I run the following command to create a nexux 6p, it works fine...

```
avdmanager create avd -n Nexus6p4 -k "system-images;android-24;google_apis_playstore;x86" --device "Nexus 6P"
```

But when I run the following command...

```
avdmanager create avd -n Pixel3 -k "system-images;android-24;google_apis_playstore;x86" --device "pixel_3a"
```

I get the following error...

> Error: No device found matching --device pixel_3

This error message doesn't make any send because when I run *avdmanager list devices*

I get the following entry...

> id: 23 or "pixel_3a"
> Name: Pixel 3a
> OEM : Google

So the device definitely exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can list the available hardware / device configurations with

```
avdmanager list device
```

which gives

```
...
---------
id: 14 or "Nexus 9"
    Name: Nexus 9
    OEM : Google
---------
id: 15 or "Nexus One"
    Name: Nexus One
    OEM : Google
---------
id: 16 or "Nexus S"
    Name: Nexus S
    OEM : Google
---------
id: 17 or "pixel"
    Name: Pixel
    OEM : Google
---------
id: 18 or "pixel_c"
    Name: Pixel C
    OEM : Google
---------
id: 19 or "pixel_xl"
    Name: Pixel XL
    OEM : Google
---------
...
```

There is a difference between device configuration (which is what `avdmanager` uses) and the skin (which the GUI Android Virtual Device Manager uses)

AFAIK you can't use the skin with command, just the configuration (resolution, RAM, etc.)

So I think

```
avdmanager create avd -n Pixel3 
    -k "system-images;android-24;google_apis_playstore;x86" 
    --device 17
```

should work for you.